# Which chart type should i choose to show change in values between 2 dates?

Tags: charts, highcharts

I am using Highcharts, but my question is in general. I want to know which chart is a perfect match to show change in values between 2 dates.

E.g The lending rate e.g
29-Aug : 21.2 
30-Aug : 21.3

The change is 0.1 million.

Which chart type should i choose to show this little difference clearly noticeable .?

Comment: So you would like to show big values and small values on the same chart? You can use multiple y axes in this case. Look at this example: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume

Comment: i want to complete only 2 values, and show the difference in a visual way. like, value of today vs value of yesterday. So in every case i will have 2 values and the difference. I dont think that candlestick is a good match for my requirement. Thanks for responding. Any other idea ?

Comment: I never thought candlestick would be good idea, I just wanted to show you an example of chart with two y axes.

Answer (score 6):

If you're comparing two dates/values, I would recommend using a [bar chart](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/bar-charts/). (If you're comparing values over months or years, I would suggest using a [line](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/line-charts/) or [area](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/area-charts/) chart.) You can better emphasize the difference between the two lending rate values by [specifying the minimum, maximum, and step scale values](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/basic-elements/configure-chart-scales/#scale-formatting-min-max-step) so that the 0.1 million difference can be clearly illustrated. See the below demo:

```js
var myConfig = {
  type: 'bar',
  title: {
    text: 'Lending Rate',
    fontFamily: 'Georgia'
  },
  utc: true,
  timezone: 0,
  scaleX: {
    transform: {
      type: 'date',
      all: '%M %d, %Y'
    },
    step: 86400000,
    item: {
      fontSize: 10
    }
  },
  scaleY: {
    values: '21.1:21.4:0.1',
    format: '%vM',
    decimals: 1,
    item: {
      fontSize: 10
    },
    guide: {
      lineStyle: 'dotted'
    }
  },
  plot: {
    barWidth: '50%',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    backgroundColor: '#99ccff',
    valueBox: {
      text: '%v million',
      fontSize: 12,
      fontColor: 'gray',
      fontWeight: 'normal'
    },
    tooltip: {
      text: '%v million'
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      values: [
        [1472428800000, 21.2],
        [1472515200000, 21.3],
      ]
    }
  ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 400, 
 width: 600 
});
```

```html
<script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>

<div id='myChart'></div>
```

For more on scale customization and formatting, see this [X/Y-Axis Scales Tutorial](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/basic-elements/configure-chart-scales/). The [value boxes](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/basic-elements/value-boxes/) and [tooltips](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/basic-elements/tooltips/) can also be used to provide further information about the node values.

Hope that helps. I'm a member of the [ZingChart](https://www.zingchart.com/) team, and happy to answer further questions.

Answer (score 2):

A simple bar chart with data labels to indicate the respective values would be helpful to show users there is a very small change in value.

See the code snippet below. I modified one of the basic Highcharts demos for a bar chart with your example values.

I hope this is helpful for you!

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: { type: 'bar' },
        title: { text: 'Sample Chart' },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['29-Aug','30-Aug'],
            title: { text: null }
        },
        yAxis: { min: 0 },
        tooltip: { valueSuffix: ' million' },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    crop: false,
                    overflow: 'none',
                    enabled: true,
                    style: { fontSize: '18px' }
                }
            }
        },
        legend: { enabled: false },
        credits: { enabled: false },
        series: [{
            name: 'Sample Series',
            data: [21.2,21.3]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width: 450px; height: 250px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```